# Why do I get this error on Oracle Database 12c?

Tags: c#, .net, database, oracle

I want to use Oracle Continuous Query Notification with the below code, but I get the following error:

> ORA-65131: The feature Continuous Query Notification is not supported
> in a pluggable database.

on the line `da.Fill(ds, tablename);`

I have added data connections in Visual Studio to SYS and HR (SYS.PDBORCL and HR.PDBORCL). Using SYS, I have granted change notification to HR.

I'm using Oracle Database 12.1.0.1.0.

You may find below the Form:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, con);
    con.Open();

    cmd.AddRowid = true;
    OracleDependency dep = new OracleDependency(cmd);
    cmd.Notification.IsNotifiedOnce = false;

    dep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnMyNotificaton);
    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
    da.Fill(ds, tablename);
    dataGrid1.SetDataBinding(ds,tablename);

    Show();
    Refresh();
}
```

Also, this is the connection string:

```
public static string constr = "User Id=hr; Password=Mypassword; Pooling=false; Data Source=PDBORCL;";
```

Can you help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is fairly clear, you don’t have access to that feature using a pluggable database in your version.

12.1.0.1 was the first Oracle release with multitenant, not every existing feature was able to be recoded to work with the new architecture immediately. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/READM/chapter12102.htm#READM120 Has a list of all the restrictions in this first version.

Luckily, 12.2.0.1 included a lot of these features, including Continuous Query Notification. See how it is no longer a restriction in https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/readm/features-not-available-12-2.html#GUID-73783D49-948A-4260-A6A3-23FE71A3B7C3

For new builds (in March of 2021) you should be looking at Oracle 19c.